# How to modify a grid in adminhtml in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to modify the app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php file with my own grid, which is located at app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Grid.php

I tried to add this code in my config.xml :

```
<blocks>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <customer_grid>MyCompany_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid</customer_grid>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

but it didn't work, can somedboy help me?

[edit] I updated my code with the help of the first answer but this didn't work either, I've got a server error. My grid file works well if I replace my core file [/edit]

Answer (score 1):

The config maps rewrites *through* the class group ("adminhtml" in this case):

```
<blocks>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <customer_grid>Tegeso_Codepromo_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid</customer_grid>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

See [`Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassName()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php#L1232) to see exactly how this works.

Comment: Error means that *something* is working. You should update your question with this information including the exact error message